# Change name of EventObject fields

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a possibility to set a specific field name for event title? 
e.g.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            name  : 'event1', //instead of 'title'
            start_date  : '2010-01-01' //instead of 'start'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Event Object` will have standard fields and see [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) at the bottom of the page. You can have any additional non-standard fields. So you could add a `name` field but you would still need a title field as it is required.

> In addition to the fields above, you may also include your own non-standard fields in each Event Object. FullCalendar will not modify or delete these fields. For example, developers often include a description field for use in callbacks such as eventRender.

You also have the option to set a custom name for the [startParam](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/startParam/), [endParam](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/endParam/) and [timezoneParam](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/timezoneParam/). So you can use these to change your `start` and `end` to `start_date` and `end_date`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to customize the 'title' param mostly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may be able to change it by editing the `fullCalendar.js` file but as far as how easy or difficult that is, I do not know.

Comment: There are >13k lines of code, so yesterday i tried to find all "event.title" and replace it with "event.name", but it didn't work :(

Comment: One approach could be to use [eventDataTransform](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/) to translate whatever your custom fields are called into **title** and **start** (at a minimum) that fullcalendar requires. see fiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/mpwebq56/

Comment: @smcd +1 I did not know about this, you should post as an answer.

Comment: Anyway, I fetch events as a function, but they come in different format. So I can do the same transformations as _eventDataTransform_ does inside this function. The main idea was to change one param and do nothing instead of transforming every object into another. It seems the only way is to edit `fullCalendar.js` which is a bit consumung move :)

Comment: @Meehanick The downside to editing fullcalendar itself is it becomes burdensome to upgrade it as new features or fixes are implemented.